# How to pair similar objects from two sorted lists?

Tags: scala, list

I'm trying to learn Scala (2.10). In this exercise, I have a case class:

```
case class Entry(name: String, version: String) { }
```

I have two sequences of such objects sorted by their name attribute:

```
S1 = E1, E3, E4
S2 = F1, F2, F4
```

I want to construct a new sequence:

```
S3 = (E1, F1), (None, F2), (E3, None), (E4, F4)
```

pairing them by their name attribute, preferrably without having to iterate more than once over each list.

All my solutions for this problem becomes extremely imperative in style (e.g. conditionally incrementing two integers and using .get()). I hope some kind soul can suggest a more functional approach.

Comment: Are they sorted by _name_ not version? Are you pairing them by _name_ not version?

Comment: Sorry, the naming were a bit confusing; maybe they should have been named EA, EB, EC, et cetera. I don't think it really matters much, tho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean by their `version` attribute, judging from the example?

You can use lists and recursion:

```
def pair(s1: List[Entry], s2: List[Entry]): List[(Option[Entry], Option[Entry])] =
  (s1, s2) match {
    case (Entry(_, v1) :: _, Entry(_, v2) :: _) if v1 == v2 =>
      (Some(s1.head), Some(s2.head)) :: pair(s1.tail, s2.tail)
    case (Entry(_, v1) :: s1t, Entry(_, v2) :: s2t) =>
      if (v1 < v2) (Some(s1.head), None) :: pair(s1.tail, s2)
      else (None, Some(s2.head)) :: pair(s1, s2.tail)
    case (Nil, s2) => s2.map(entry => (None, Some(entry))
    case (s1, Nil) => s1.map(entry => (Some(entry), None)
  }
```

Essentially, you progress to the list comparing their heads, and taking both heads if the version is the same, or taking only the smaller one. You then recursively do the same for the tail of the lists. If one of the lists turns out to be empty, you just map the remaining elements of the other list into pairs of `None` and the entry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, `EX` means `name="E"` and `version="X"`, and you want to pair things with the same version. Here is my solution, which unfortunately takes square time, so don't use it if efficiency matters...

```
val versions = (S1 ++ S2) map { _.version } groupBy (identity) keys
val sortedVersions = versions.toSeq.sorted
sortedVersions map { ver => (S1 find { _.version==ver }, S2 find { _.version==ver }) }
```

or if you know in advance what are the possible versions, just make a sequence of that and execute the final line.

```
Seq("1", "2", "3", "4") map { ver => (S1 find { _.version==ver }, S2 find { _.version==ver }) }
```

Result:

```
 ArrayBuffer((Some(Entry(E,1)),Some(Entry(F,1))), (None,Some(Entry(F,2))), (Some(Entry(E,3)),None), (Some(Entry(E,4)),Some(Entry(F,4))))
```

Note that instead of `(None, F2)` I have `(None, Some(F2))` here, as pairing `None` with `Some` seems more consistent.

BTW, `case class(...)` is sufficient, you don't need to add empty brackets `{ }` after it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't show the details on my ipad ;), but if there aren't many gaps in the numbers you could scan through each list, inserting Nones in the gaps by building up new lists or vectors (vectors are faster) using a recursive algorithm like axel22 showed, then zip the collections together.